# What does 'already' with future tense mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning, future-tense

> "Yes..." said Ron softly, "It's the only way... I've got to be taken."
>   "NO!" Harry and Hermione shouted.
>   "That's chess!" snapped Ron. "You've got to make some sacrifices! I take one step forward and she'll take me –– that leaves you free to checkmate the king, Harry!"
>   "But ––"
>   "Do you want to stop Snape or not?"
>   "Ron ––"
>   "Look, if you don't hurry up, he'll **already** have the Stone!" There was no alternative.
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Does *already* with future tense mean "at once, right away", or what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Already' here means 'by then.' If you go slow, Snape will have got the stone by then. So, better hurry up.